Использование паттерна PageObject для автотестов
Изучаю использование паттерна PageObject, есть ли возможность использовать ниже указанный код и для других видов? например есть еще пиццы с другим названием и необходимо и для них тот же локатор и действие использовать


class PizzaAddBasket {
    constructor(item) {
      this.locator = $(`div.slick-track a[title="${item}"] + a.button`);
    }
    submit() {
      this.locator.click();
    }
  }
  module.exports = PizzaAddBasket;
  



Или надо использовать схожее с ниже указанным кодом для других видов пицц?


get pizzaAddBasket() {
    return new PizzaAddBasket("Пицца «4 в 1»");
  }



Вызываю паттерн таким образом


DataPage.pizzaAddBasket.submit();



